Apple push notification
We use amazon and firebase push notification. We received this message from apple. Do we need do anything?
https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09za8wzy

The Certification Authority (CA) for Apple Push Notification service (APNs) is changing. APNs will update the server certificates in sandbox on January 20, 2025, and in production on February 24, 2025. All developers using APNs will need to update their application’s Trust Store to include the new server certificate: SHA-2 Root : USERTrust RSA Certification Authority certificate.
To ensure a smooth transition and avoid push notification delivery failures, please make sure that both old and new server certificates are included in the Trust Store before the cut-off date for each of your application servers that connect to sandbox and production.
At this time, you don’t need to update the APNs SSL provider certificates issued to you by Apple.


Same in my case. We are using one signal for push notif and it seems that we don't have any actions on our side. One signal is the who needs to incorporate this update.

Asked the same question in the Firebase Google group. Seems like the Firebase team will update the server certificate on their end:

You are correct. Firebase servers will handle these updates.

https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/KM9qydwykyg/m/V130qhduAQAJ

If you are using third party services like Firebase or OneSignal, then You don't have need to do anything in your app side... Firebase and OneSignal will update the certificate on their end.
